# GIPHY API key not being set

Tags: ios, swift, giphy-api

I'm trying to incorporate the GIPHY API into my project.

In my AppDelegate, I set the API Key to the public beta key (just to test it out):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    SwiftyGiphyAPI.shared.apiKey = "dc6zaTOxFJmzC"


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

And this is from a public class `SwiftyGiphyAPI`:

```
public static let publicBetaKey = "dc6zaTOxFJmzC"

/// Access the Giphy API through the shared singleton.
public static let shared: SwiftyGiphyAPI = SwiftyGiphyAPI()

/// Before you can use SwiftyGiphy, you need to set your API key.
public var apiKey: String? {
    didSet {

        if apiKey == SwiftyGiphyAPI.publicBetaKey
        {
            print("****************************************************************************************************************************")
            print("*                                                                                                                          *")
            print("*     IMPORTANT: You seem to be using Giphy's public beta key. Please change this to a production key before shipping.     *")
            print("*     Apply for one here: http://api.giphy.com/submit                                                                      *")
            print("*                                                                                                                          *")
            print("****************************************************************************************************************************")
            print("")
        }
    }
}
```

And when the Controller opens, the trending section is supposed to show the trending GIFs, this is the beginning of that function:

```
   func getTrending(limit: Int = 25, rating: SwiftyGiphyAPIContentRating = .pg13, offset: Int? = nil, completion: GiphyMultipleGIFResponseBlock?)
{
    guard apiKey != nil || !isUsingDefaultAPIBase else {
        print("ATTENTION: You need to set your Giphy API key before using SwiftyGiphy.")

        completion?(networkError(description: NSLocalizedString("You need to set your Giphy API key before using SwiftyGiphy.", comment: "You need to set your Giphy API key before using SwiftyGiphy.")), nil)
        return
    }
```

I'm getting the print statement that `You need to set your Giphy API key before using SwiftyGiphy.`

I think it's because `SwiftyGiphyAPI.shared.apiKey` is still an optional, so it's being read by `SwiftyGiphyAPI` as nil. I've tried some optional chaining, but maybe I did it wrong.

I'm sure there's a simple fix I'm missing.

Also, here's a link to the GIPHY docs if that helps: [GIPHY Docs](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/)

Thanks in advance for your help!